# Magento custom adminhtml template gets overwritten by default template

Tags: magento-1.9, module, magento-community, extensions

I want to add a custom field to the order info page in the admin section. Based on all the tutorials I read this should be a simple task. However I found out that my custom template gets overwritten by the default one.

Here is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_MyModule>
            <version>0.1.1</version>    <!-- Version number of your module -->
        </MyCompany_MyModule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mymodule>
                <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Model</class>
            </mymodule>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <mymodule>
                <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Helper</class>
            </mymodule>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <mymodule_attributes_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>MyCompany_MyModule</module>
                    <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </mymodule_attributes_setup>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <mymodule>
                <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Block</class>
            </mymodule>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_view_info>MyCompany_MyModule_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info</sales_order_view_info>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
     </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyCompany_MyModule</module>
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <mymodule_options>
                                            <title>MyModule Options</title>
                                        </mymodule_options>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file>
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

In the config.xml, I defined my module's Block to rewrite the Mage_AdminHtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info.

Here is my MyCompany_MyModule.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_MyModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </MyCompany_MyModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Here is my custom block file: ../mycompany/mymodule/Block/Sales/Order/View/Info.php

```
<?php

class MyCompany_MyModule_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('mymodule/sales/order/view/info.phtml');
    }
}
```

In my Block file I override the parent's template.

Here is my layout file mymodule.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="order_info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>mymodule/sales/order/view/info.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <block type="mymodule/sales_order_view_info" name="mymodule_sales_order_view_info" template="mymodule/sales/order/view/info.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>
</layout>
```

In my template file info.phtml, simply print out `<p>Hello</p>`

My template file symlinks to magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/mymodule/sales/order/view/info.phtml
My layout file symlinks to
magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/mymodule.xml

I have turned on Allow Symlink in the system configuration.

Now that's should be everything I need to do based on all the posts and tutorials I read. However my custom module doesn't show.

I checked Exception log, nothing in there. So I logged out the templates name in class Mage_Core_Block_Template located at magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:

```
/**
 * Set path to template used for generating block's output.
 *
 * @param string $template
 * @return Mage_Core_Block_Template
 */
public function setTemplate($template)
{
    Mage::log("template: $template");
    $this->_template = $template;
    return $this;
}
```

Now in the system.log, I see the following:

```
2015-05-07T23:56:16+00:00 DEBUG (7): template: mymodule/sales/order/view/info.phtml
2015-05-07T23:56:16+00:00 DEBUG (7): template: sales/order/view/info.phtml
```

So my custom Block gets called, but right after it loads my custom template, it gets overwritten by the default one.

What am I doing wrong here? Btw I'm using Magento CE 1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  tag should be used if you create a module that impacts an other one.
and your declaration file `(app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml)` this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_MyModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Sales />
            </depends>
        </MyCompany_MyModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

so finally your xml will look like

**EDIT**

to use adminhtml custom theme

if you are using like this in frontend `design\frontend\default\yourtheme`

then in admin you can also use `design\adminhtml\default\yourtheme`

you it should work like your custom in admin area please don't put in base else when you going to upgrade your magento version it may create issue.

i hope it will work for you.

Comment: Hey I tried this, but same result. Is there any other Mage modules that should be added into the depends section in order to overwrite Sales_Order_View_Info block?

Comment: @BboyJeans, it's enough to give Mage_sales. You should have to debug in detail though.:(

Comment: Hey I finally figured it out. I needed to put my layout in `magento/app/design/adminhtml/base/default/layout/mymodule.xml`, and put my template in `magento/app/design/adminhtml/base/default/template/mymodule/sales/order/view/info.phtml` I found this by directly changing the default layout file and log the info out. Then I saw it tries to load my template from that directory. Wried thing is I don't have `app/design/adminhtml/base` directory, I only have `app/design/adminhtml/default` directory, I ended up creating it by myself.

Comment: @BboyJeans, use my updated answer.if its useful to you pls dont forget to acpt it

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I think this time I finally got it solved, I adde the following in my config.xml:     `<admin>
         <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <mymodule after="Mage_Adminhtml">MyModule_FruugoApi</mymodule>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>` And put my stuff back in .../default/default, it's working now. Also I noticed that symlinks to the layout file isn't working, I had to copy the file to that directory, very odd.